# How can i only send and verify Tokens only in Djoser Django and not a pair of Token and Uid

Tags: javascript, python, django, react-native, djoser

I am trying to make a mobile app, and I only want to use Djoser to send the token once a user registers on the app. The most significant issue I have is that Djoser sends both a UID and a token, which I don't want. I only want it to send the Token a user can enter into the verify email field on the mobile app. How can I do that using Djoser in Django?

```
DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SET_USERNAME_RETYPE': True,
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'users.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user': 'users.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
    }
}
```